# Are the java.util.* packages only meant for utility classes?

Tags: java, standards, package, utility

I am programming in Java and was told to refactor some code to coding standards. I was told that util packages are meant for static utility classes and not application functionality. Is this correct? What exactly does this mean? Also, considering the "java.util" package contains Collection interface, how else could I accomplish tasks requiring lists?

Comment: Um if you were told exactly this what you were told was wrong. Can you clarify that's exactly what you were told? *"Don't use java.util classes except in a static utility class?"* That seems a bizarre assertion.

Comment: Go back and understand what "refactor" means and look at the "coding standards" you are being asked to transform some code into.  Focus on your coding standards first and figure out how the "code" does not match the standards.  Then look to transform (refactor) to match

Comment: To be clear though, you shouldn't be putting _your own code_ into java.util…

Comment: Maybe the util package in the app you're working on follows this convention, but this isn't globally applicable.

Comment: the only real conventions as far as Java packages go is that there are no conventions

Comment: @Radiodef "One obvious issue was the util package.  Util packages are usually meant for static utility classes, not for application functionality." is the exact quote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whoever told you that was wrong — or you misunderstood. `java.util.*` has a *bunch* of extremely useful, extremely common classes, most of which are not utility classes (in the common sense of "a class with only/mostly static methods for common tasks"). For instance, `List` is in `java.util`, along with its commonly-used implements `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. Ditto `Map`/`HashMap`/`TreeMap`, `Set`/`HashSet`/`TreeSet`, and many others.

Comment: I very well could have misunderstood. Either way, at least I now know to discuss further and get clarification. I just wanted to make sure this wasn't a huge rule that I am missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are no hard and fast rules about what would appear in a util package. To quote the javadoc `java.util` contains

> the collections framework, legacy collection classes, event model, date and time facilities, internationalization, and miscellaneous utility classes (a string tokenizer, a random-number generator, and a bit array).

As you rightly say this is much more that only utility classes. In this case the person seems to be taking the word utility and package util a bit too literally.

I would say that a util package is for miscellaneous useful classes that don't have enough similar classes to justify grouping them in their own package.